# How to pass array of C Boolean values with MPI?

Tags: c, mpi

I have an array of boolean values that I'd like to use with MPI, but as far as I have searched there is no `MPI_BOOL` type. The programming language is C and I'm using `bool` from `stdbool.h`. The size of bool on my machine is 1 byte.

Do I just use some other MPI type? I'd rather not do this in the interest of keeping the size of the array to transfer as small as possible.

Comment: There isn't as you said a MPI_Bool type in C. One way is to convert your array to integers with 0 and 1.Also in C++ there is MPI:BOOL type if you are insteresting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `MPI_C_BOOL` for type `_Bool`.

Note the C++ bindings have been removed from the MPI standard.